# useref.assets break gulp pipeline

Tags: gulp, gulp-useref

when I try to use gulp-useref on my index.html file, pipeline breaks and the task won't finish
what is wrong with it?
I have testet useref on my html source and it was fine

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
  var htmlFilter = $.filter(['*.html', '**/*.html']);
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');
  var assets;

  return gulp.src(
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '*.html')
  )
  .pipe($.debug({title: 'after src:'}))
  .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
  .pipe($.debug({title: 'after useref.assets():'}))
  .pipe($.rev())
  .pipe(cssFilter)
  .pipe($.minifyCss())
  .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
  .pipe(assets.restore())
  .pipe($.useref())
  .pipe($.revReplace())
  .pipe(htmlFilter) 
  .pipe($.minifyHtml({
    empty: true,
    spare: true,
    quotes: true,
    conditionals: true
  }))
  .pipe(htmlFilter.restore())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
  .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
});
```

debug won't show after useref.assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [gulp-useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref) github page:

> Changes under the hood have made the code more efficient and simplified the API. Since the API has changed, please observe the usage examples below.

Assets is no longer available so I think that's your problem.

Comment: So, what is the preferred workaround for this? Using filters?

Comment: Yes I used filters. However, I can't get the sourcemaps working using the new API and lazypipe as they suggest

Comment: Well thanks, I ended up ditching it because I needed RTL support and my css were added dynamically and I couldn't use this, I don't remember why but it was a solid issue that we discussed in our team :D Thanks for your answer